# How to span image over 2 table rows?

Tags: html, html-table

I am trying to span background image over 2 table rows but this does not seem to work.

Html:

```
<table id="branchTable">
 <thead>
  <th align="center">Tel.</th>
  <th align="center">Fax</th>
  <td rowspan="2" id="branch-logo"> d</td>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <td align="center">${_branch?.tel}</td>
  <td align="center">${_branch?.fax}</td>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

css:

```
#branch-logo {
    background-image: url(/public/images/logo.png);
    height:53px;
    width:100px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left;
}
```

The image seems to be pushing the row down and not spanning accross.

**UPDATE**

```
<table id="branchTable">
 <tr id="thead">
  <th align="center">Tel.</th>
  <th align="center">Fax</th>
  <td rowspan="2" id="branch-logo"> d</td>
 </tr>
 <tr id="tbody">
  <td align="center">${_branch?.tel}</td>
  <td align="center">${_branch?.fax}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

rowspan does not seem to work between tbody and thead. Using tr does the trick.

Comment: I don't see `#branch-logo` anywhere in your posted html. and your table has 1 row. In fact, due to malformed HTML it really has no rows whatsoever.

Comment: Well pointer, silly mistake...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot your `<tr>`s in your table. That's probably what causes it to misbehave.

And as Scott says, you use `logo` in your html and `branch-logo` in your css.

**Edit**: In addition, I'm not at all sure if all major browsers support rowspanning a cell over a thead and a tbody. That would take some testing.